# OneLogin ruby client how to identify the user's nameID

Tags: ruby, saml, onelogin

I am using the OneLogin SAML Test Connector as a simulated IDP with the ruby-saml gem and the supplied sample program. That's working fine.

In my real-world app, we are the SP and there are multiple identity providers, each of which will have multiple users who need to SSO to our app.

I have observed that in the sample app, my AuthnRequest does not define the user's nameID (email address) anywhere, but instead it is appended to the IDP URL in the form of a numeric id. e.g. `https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/5551212` where app.onelogin.com identifies the IDP and 5551212 identifies the "user". I realize that when onelogin is the IDP the "user" is actually an app id, but in our case we want it to identify an actual user, not an app.

1. Is it correct that the AuthnRequest does not contain a nameID element?
2. Should I identify the user in the IDP's URL using a numeric ID? The numeric id would have to be shared offline between the parties, and would have to be transmitted in the initiating URL. I like this approach because it doesn't expose any identifying information in the URL, e.g. an email address.
3. Should I identify the user by Base64-encoding the email address and appending that to the URL? This is less secure, but it might be ok since the transmission will always be encrypted with SSL. And it avoids the offline handshake and sharing a numeric ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AuthnRequest does not define the user's nameID (email address)
>   anywhere, but instead it is appended to the IDP URL in the form of a
>   numeric id.

This is not true, that numeric id identify internally the IdP, not the user.

1. Yes, check the [SAML standard](http://www.datypic.com/sc/saml2/e-samlp_AuthnRequest.html), saml:Subject is optional. And [SAML2int](http://saml2int.org/profile/current/#section8) profile says that AuthNRequest message MUST NOT contain a saml:Subject.
2. No
3. No

You don't need to pass user information to the IdP, you should simply send an AuthNRequest to the SSO endpoint and a form to place a username/password gonna be showed to the user (if already exists an active session this authentication is not required. Then a SAMLResponse will be send back to the SP's Assertion Consumer Service endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So in the AuthnRequest I include a NameIDPolicy telling the IDP that I want an email address back, and that will come to me in the Response document's Assertion. (actually I think it's the AttributeStatement)

Comment: Yes, the AuthnRequest will contain for example:
<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"  />

Then the IdP will send a SAMLResponse with:
 <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">user@example.com</saml:NameID>


The AttributeStatement is a different element. I recommend you to visit https://www.samltool.com/ and learn more about the SAML standard.

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  Check out https://www.samltool.com/base64.php to help with looking at Response attributes.